# Get value of variable that stores a a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a SharePoint question, but I feel more like it is a javascript question also. I'm using this great tool to fill some of the fields in my SharePoint list (web part). It works great when I do this one by one, but I'm trying to request multiple column values, but I can't get it to work.

```
var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
fieldNames: ["ID", "Name", "SIP Address"],
debug: false
});
```

How can I get specific column value (e.g. "Name") from this array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://spservices.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#jquery.SPServices-2013.01ALPHA5.js) it appears that the `SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser()` function returns an associative array with the keys being the `fieldNames` that were passed to it.

This means to access the field you can use

```
thisUserValues.Name
```

Or

```
thisUserValues['Name']
```

Disclaimer: I have no experience with sharepoint or this particular jQuery library.